# Verilog HDL Loop Statement error: loop with non-constant loop condition must terminate

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am completely new to Verilog and I have to know quite a bit of it fairly soon for a course I am taking in university. I am play around with my Altera DE2 board and quartis2 and learning the ins and outs.

I am trying to make a counter which is turned on and off by a switch.
So far, the counter counts and resets based on a key press.

This is my error:

```
Error (10119): Verilog HDL Loop Statement error at my_first_counter_enable.v(19): 
loop with non-constant loop condition must terminate within 250 iterations
```

I understand I am being asked to provide a loop variable, but even doing so I get an error.

```
module my_first_counter_enable(SW,CLOCK_50,LEDR,KEY);

    input CLOCK_50;
    input [17:0] SW;
    input KEY;

   output [17:0] LEDR;

   reg [32:0] count;
   wire reset_n;
   wire enable;

   assign reset_n = KEY;
   assign enable = SW[0];
   assign LEDR = count[27:24];


   always@ (posedge CLOCK_50 or negedge reset_n) begin
       while(enable) begin
           if(!reset_n)
               count = 0;
           else
               count = count + 1;
       end
    end

endmodule
```

I hope someone can point out my error in my loop and allow me to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want to use a `while` loop there.  How about:

```
   always@ (posedge CLOCK_50 or negedge reset_n) begin
           if(!reset_n)
               count <= 0;
           else if (enable)
               count <= count + 1;
    end
```

I also added non-blocking assignments `<=`, which are more appropriate for synchronous logic.

Answer (score 2):

The block will trigger every time there is a positive edge of the clock. Where you had a `while` loop does not mean anything in hardware, it would still need a clock to drive the flip flops.

While loops can be used in testbeches to drive stimulus

```
integer x;
initial begin
  x = 0;
  while (x<1000) begin
    data_in = 2**x ; //or stimulus read from file etc ...
    x=x+1;
  end
end
```

I find `for` loops or `repeat`  to be of more use though:

```
integer x;
initial begin
  for (x=0; x<1000; x=x+1) begin
    data_in = 2**x ; //or stimulus read from file etc ...
  end
end

initial begin
  repeat(1000) begin
    data_in = 'z; //stimulus read from file etc (no loop variable)...
  end
end
```

NB: personally I would also add begin end to every thing to avoid adding extra lines later and wondering why they always or never get executed, especially while new to the language. It also has the added benefit of making the indenting look a little nicer.

```
always@ (posedge CLOCK_50 or negedge reset_n) begin
  if(!reset_n) begin
    count <= 'b0;
  end
  else if (enable) begin
    count <= count + 1;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Title**

Error (10119): Verilog HDL Loop Statement error at : loop with non-constant loop condition must terminate within  iterations
Description

This error may appear in the Quartus® II software when synthesis iterates through a loop in Verilog HDL for more than the synthesis loop limit. This limit prevents synthesis from potentially running into an infinite loop. By default, this loop limit is set to 250 iterations.

**Workaround / Fix**

To work around this error, the loop limit can be set using the VERILOG_NON_CONSTANT_LOOP_LIMIT option in the Quartus II Settings File (.qsf). For example:

set_global_assignment -name VERILOG_NON_CONSTANT_LOOP_LIMIT 300

Comment: I had seen this also, but when putting it into my code I got an error about this line of code.

Comment: As it states you need to put it in the settings file, not your code. And you do not have an error in your code you are simply going over the limit. So you will need to either, increase the limit, or take an approach to the liking of @toolic answer :-)

Comment: oh! alright i guess I miss understood. I will look into setting that in my settings file